# How to add a String Array in a JSON object?

Tags: android, json, arrays

I am trying to create this JSON object on android. I am stuck on how to add a string array in the object.

```
A = {
    "class" : "4" ,
    "name" : ["john", "mat", "jason", "matthew"]
    }
```

This is the code that I have written :

```
import org.json.JSONObject;

JSONObject school = new JSONObject();

school.put("class","4");
school.put("name", ["john", "mat", "jason", "matthew"] );
```

But the last line gives an error. Any way past this?

Answer (score 58, accepted):

Little improper approach suggested by Tom. Optimised code would be:

```
ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
list.add("john");
list.add("mat");
list.add("jason");
list.add("matthew");

JSONObject school = new JSONObject();

school.put("class","4");
school.put("name", new JSONArray(list));
```

Comment: This is the correct Java way of doing this. Selected answer would work but  not the right way to do this.

Comment: To import the right package you should write:

import org.json.simple.JSONArray;
on top of java class.

And if you are using Maven, add

 <dependency>
    <groupId>com.googlecode.json-simple</groupId>
    <artifactId>json-simple</artifactId>
    <version>1.1</version>  
</dependency>
to pom.xml. Then, Download sources & dependencies and Reimport.

Answer (score 6):

You're getting an error because your last line is invalid Java.

```
school.put("name", new JSONArray("[\"john\", \"mat\", \"jason\", \"matthew\"]"));
```

Comment: This solved it... Actually I had to make a new JSONArray and put all the data in it. Thanx a lot

Comment: This is the wrong way of doing this in java , even though it solved your current issue

Answer (score 3):

You are getting error because of this.

```
school.put("name", ["john", "mat", "jason", "matthew"] );
                   ^                                 ^
```

Do like this.

```
school.put("name", new JSONArray("[\"john\", \"mat\", \"jason\", \"matthew\"]"));
```

Comment: @VenkateshShukla What problem you have now?

Answer (score 2):

@bhavindesai's, answer is great answer. Here is another way to solve this issue. You can simply do it using Json Simple library. Here is the gradle

```
compile 'com.googlecode.json-simple:json-simple:1.1'
```

Here is sample code:

```
org.json.simple.JSONObject jsonObject=new org.json.simple.JSONObject();
jsonObject.put("Object","String Object");

ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
            list.add("john");
            list.add("mat");
            list.add("jason");
            list.add("matthew");

            jsonObject.put("List",list);
```

That's it. :)

Answer (score 2):

As bhavindesai noted,

```
ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
list.add("john");
list.add("mat");
list.add("jason");
list.add("matthew");

JSONObject school = new JSONObject();

school.put("class","4");
school.put("name", new JSONArray(list));
```

is a much better and cleaner approach.

To import the right package you should write:

```
import org.json.simple.JSONArray;
```

on top of java class.

And if you are using Maven, add

```
 <dependency>
    <groupId>com.googlecode.json-simple</groupId>
    <artifactId>json-simple</artifactId>
    <version>1.1</version>  
</dependency>
```

to pom.xml. Then, Download sources & dependencies and Reimport. I answered though I used commenting, since commenting screwed up the code indentation.